# getting only the first match from a 'doseq' in clojure

Tags: loops, clojure

Say I want to find only the first match of a condition through a series of numbers, or in a range:

```
(doseq [x (range 3 12)
        :when (= 0 (mod x 4))
        ]
  (println x)
  )
```

The code will print `all` the numbers which is dividable by for in the range of 3 to 11, so it'd be `4` and `8`, but what if I just want the first match which is `4`?

Comment: `The code will return all the numbers...` no this code returns `nil`, it prints 4 and 8 though. Have a look at clojure functions [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) and [first](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/first)

Comment: @birdspider my bad. I edited the question. just saw your `first` and `filter` reference. Love you man.

Comment: `doseq` always returns `nil` there is no "first match" you can get from [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doseq always returns nil there is no "first match" you can get from doseq.

What you can do is take your `(range 3 12)` filter all the ones that satisfy `(= 0 (mod x 4))` from it, and finally fetch the first like so:

```
(->> 
  (range 3 12)
  (filter #(= 0 (mod % 4)))
  first)
; => 4

; this is eqivalent to the above it you are unfamiliar with `->>
; (first (filter #(= 0 (mod % 4)) (range 3 12)))
```